# NodeJs: Sending picture with Express (Multer)

Tags: node.js, image, file, express, multer

I have this code

```
app.get('/imgs/:id', function(req, res) {
    // Validate that req.params.id is 16 bytes hex string
    // Get the stored image type for this image
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, req.params.id));
    stream.on("readable", function() {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', "image/jpeg")
        stream.pipe(res)
    })
    stream.on('error', (e) => {
        res.redirect(404, "404")
    })
});
```

Now the problem is that I always get an error of

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

because I used the `res.setHeader` function.
However, i don't know how to solve it. Let's say I want to use in a page, that has obviously the `res.send()` function has well,
the `<img src="imgs/pic">`, then I must set the header for the this page request to `"image/jpeg"` because otherwise the browser wouldn't know it's an image and won't show it as one.

What can I do then?

Comment: The `readable` event can be sent multiple times, which is causing the error, but using `res.sendFile()` as suggested in the answer is probably a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Check Express response document [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res). Try this code

```
app.get('/imgs/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(req.params.id, {root: UPLOAD_PATH, headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}}, function (err) {
        if(err) throw err;
    else  console.log('sent')
    })
})
```